# Multiple AJAX requests with React

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm currently developing a React application which has multiple container components each of which perform an AJAX request in `componentDidMount` to an API to return some data, which is then stored in each of the components local state.

My question is, is it a bad idea for each of these requests to fire when the page loads and have multiple AJAX requests running at once?  I tried finding if there are any browser limitations to concurrent network requests but struggled to find anything.

Another alternative would be to only run the request when the user interacts with the component. e.g. if a tab becomes active then run the request.

Does anyone have any other methods when using React and handling AJAX requests, I've looked into using Redux but think it may be a little over the top for this project and I'm not sure if it would solve the issue at hand.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify how you have multiple container components mounting at once?

Comment: There *are* browser limits to the number of concurrent requests, but they stack up (or should) so it's just a matter of time. I might argue that something like GraphQL or other request aggregation might be a better option, though, if you need all the results at (more or less) the same time. Redux is orthogonal to the question, though; you'd have the same issues with or without it.

Comment: @usedToBeFat not loads, maybe 6/7, I'm trying to see if there might be a more graceful way to handle it.

Comment: hmm. No I mean, are you loading one page that is making multiple ajax calls?

Comment: Yeah that's it, one page will load 6/7 containers each making a request, so there will be that many ajax calls happening

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is fine to perform multiple async requests at once. Many, many websites do that.

However, if it is possible to defer the calls, you should probably try and do that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your needs. Load once on a huge payload is doable, but preform incremental ajax calls would be probably the most optimized way of doing it.  Unless you have coupling and you are getting callback hell by doing them separately, otherwise I don't see a reason why you would prefer load all of them at once.